# Dependent Drop Down Jquery option list JSON error

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, mysqli

Guys I am very new in Jquery and Json trying, I am trying to create a Dependent Option list with Jquery but it's not working. I am expecting your kind help. 
here is my HTML code..

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="categoriesId">
        Categories</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="categoriesId" name="categoriesId">
        <option selcted="">Select
            Categories</option>
        <?php                   
            getCat();
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

and my `fetchProductDta.php` page code is here

```
<?php   
    require_once 'db_connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['cid'])){
        $sql = "SELECT product_id, product_name 
             FROM product WHERE categories_id = '". $cid 
             ."'";
        $result = $connect->query($sql);
        while($product = $productData->fetch_array()) {                                     
             echo "<option value='".$product['product_id']."'> 
                 ".$product['product_name']."</option>";
       }  
    }
?>
```

My Jquery Code is here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#categoriesId").change(function () {
        var cid = $("#categoriesId").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'fetchProductData.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: 'cid' + cid
                .done(function (product) {
                    console.log(product);
                    product = json.parse(product);
                    product.forEach(function (products) {
                        $('#product').appned();
                    });
                });
        });
```

Comment: fetchProductDta.php is returning HTML and not JSON.

Comment: when i am using json_encode(); it' s getting me error like this  unexpected json parse error . @NigelRen would you please help to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your jquery you have mistakes , first of all you are getting `html response` from server as  **Nigel Ren** said.So,to get that you don't need to use `json.parse` .Also i didn't find any id with name `product` in your html code.and there is no `appned` function in jquery .So,make below changes in your code to make it worked.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#categoriesId").change(function () {
            var cid = $("#categoriesId").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'fetchProductData.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {cid : cid },
                     success:function(data){

                $("#product").html(data);//here response from server will be display in #product



                 }
                    });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response . I tried your code but my bad it's not working. when i am selecting categories filed but no data is fetching in next filed. here is my #product id html " <label for="product"> Product</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="product" name="product">
        <option selcted="" value="">Select Product</option>
       </select>"

Comment: In your php code this -> `$product = $productData->fetch_array()` it should be `$product = $result->fetch_array()` because your fetching all rows in `$result`.Also you didn't fetch `$cid` you are directly passing it in query .Your query should be like this-> `SELECT product_id, product_name 
             FROM product WHERE categories_id = '". $_POST['cid']
             ."'`

Comment: thanks a lot  but i already changed my php code and i tried with this one  but the output is still same require_once 'db_connect.php';
    if(isset($_POST['cid'])){
        $sql = "SELECT product_id, product_name FROM product WHERE categories_id = ' ". $_POST['cid'] ." ' ";
        $result = $connect->query($sql);
        while($product = $result->fetch_array()) {                                     
             echo "<option value='".$product['product_id']."'> 
                 ".$product['product_name']."</option>";
       }  
    }

Comment: I have check that webpage it has this error -->`POST http://chatworld.xyz/drop.php 500 (Internal Server Error)` means something wrong on server side (php file)

Comment: I don't understand what's happening even i changed my all script php  this dropdown is kiling me yaar !!    require_once 'db_connect.php';
 if(!empty($_POST["cid"])){ 
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE categories_id = ".$_POST['cid']." AND active = 1");
    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;  
    if($rowCount > 0){
 echo '<option value="">product not available</option>';
while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ echo '<option value="'.$row['product_id'].'">'.$row['product_name'].'</option>'; }
} else { echo '<option value="">product not available</option>';
  echo 
 }
 }

Comment: Try updating your recent code in your question , it will be easy to understand !

Comment: i beg your pardon please don't mind if you have no problem can you please give me your mail or something where i can connect with you and inform you ?

Comment: Thanks a lot finally, i solve it @Swati  I really appreciate your kind help. it was server side problem and i solve those error and now it's working .

Comment: I need a help are you there ? if you are please response :) #Swati

Comment: My question Limit is done ! I am trying to update my data and i wrote this code but its not working Code is .. if (isset($_POST['steup'])){ $deposit_id = $_POST['deposit_id']; $deposit_amount= $_POST['deposit_amount']; $deposit_percentage = $_POST['deposit_percentage']; $deposit_paystatus = 1; $sql1 = " UPDATE tbl_deposit SET deposit_amount = '$deposit_amount', deposit_percentage = '$deposit_percentage', deposit_paystatus = '$ deposit_paystatus' WHERE deposit_id = '$deposit_id' "; $result = $db->query($sql1); } where is the problem please help me

Comment: did you got any error ,does all data i.e : `deposit_id`,`deposit_amount` etc have some value in it or not ,also here `'$ deposit_paystatus` there is little space remove that i.e: `'$deposit_paystatus'` .

Comment: #Swati Thanks for your kind response I solved it . there was an spelling mistake i wrote in my HTML form "Setup".  but see? i wrote in my php script is  if (isset($_POST['steup'])) . Thanks a lot again

Comment: I am creating a date filter but it's not working even not showing any error

Comment: I am creating a date filter but it's not working even not showing any error using Modal  if(isset($_POST['datewise'])) {
 $start = $_POST['start'];
 $end = $_POST['end'];
 $i=0;
$sql8 = "SELECT * FROM fdps_history WHERE deposit_id = $deposit_id AND withdraw_date BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' ORDER BY withdraw_date DESC";
  $result8 = $db->query($sql8);
  $counter8 = mysqli_num_rows($result8);
  while($data8 = $result8->fetch_array()){
   $i++;
   $withdraw_date = $data8['withdraw_date'];
  }
  }

Comment: #Swati Need a help and suggestion if you are active in online please response !!